# Navigate folders when undeleting with testdisk

Tags: data-recovery

I am trying to recover a deleted file using testdisk, but the drive is big and I have thousand of deleted files.

Testdisk knows the path of the files I have deleted : wouldn't it be possible to navigate through the folders, instead of displaying all the file? That would save myself from scrolling thousands of files

Comment: Try `photorec` instead.  `testdisk` recovers partitions and `photorec` recovers individual files.